# Dynamic Query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table with 10 columns as col_1,col_2,.... col_10. I want to write a select statement that will select a value of one of the row and from one of these 10 columns. I have a variable that will decide which column to select from. Can such query be written where the column name is dynamically decided from a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I don't have enough details, I can't give code. Instead, I'll explain.

Declare a string variable, something like:

```
declare @sql varchar(5000)
```

Set that variable to be the completed SQL string you want (as a string, and not actually querying... so you embed the row-name you want using string concatenation).

Then call: `exec(@sql)`

All set.

Comment: Make sure you're taking appropriate measures to prevent sql injection.  If the user can enter arbitrary text for the column name then you'll be in big trouble.

Comment: This is a good illustration of why it's a bad idea to let the questioner decide which answer is "correct".  The correct answer (with tons of points, below) is that you don't need dynamic sql for this particular case.  If you did need it though, then this would be the right answer.

Comment: I disagree.

This is a good illustration that popularity contexts are biased.  The requester was asking about Dynamic queries and beyond that, we are not aware of the entirity of what the requester actually wanted it for.
Proof positive that the correct answer isn't always the right answer.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, using a CASE statement:

```
SELECT CASE @MyVariable
       WHEN 1 THEN [Col_1]
       WHEN 2 THEN [Col_2]
       ...
       WHEN 10 THEN [Col_10]
       END
```

Whether this is a good idea is another question entirely.  You should use better names than Col_1, Col_2, etc.

You could also use a string substitution method, as suggested by others.  However, that is an option of last resort because it can open up your code to sql injection attacks.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a bad, denormalized design to me.

I think a better one would have the table as parent, with rows that contain a foreign key to a separate child table that contains ten rows, one for each of those columns you have now.  Let the parent table set the foreign key according to that magic value when the row is inserted or updated in the parent table.

If the child table is fairly static, this will work.

Comment: What it sounds like is a microsoft (e.g. Sharepoint) database.

Comment: It's tagged as sqlserver and sqlserver2005, so I assumed relational database.

Comment: he OP may not have any control over the schema.  Packaged applications often use this type of structure for user defined fields that are used differently depending on how the software is configured.  Although it looks inelegant, the alternatives are often worse.  For a comparison, try developing an ETL process to stage data from an insurance system that stores its whole policy document as an XML blob in an ntext column.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are running purely within Transact-SQL. What you'll need to do is dynamically create the SQL statement with your variable as the column name and use the EXECUTE command to run it.  For example:

```
EXECUTE('select ' + @myColumn + ' from MyTable')
```

Comment: Of course this particular approach is wide open to SQL Injection!

Comment: Yes, but only if @myColumn comes from user input.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a T-SQl CASE statement:

```
SELECT 'The result' =
   CASE 
     WHEN choice = 1 THEN col1
     WHEN choice = 2 THEN col2
     ...
   END
FROM sometable
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, [Joel Coehoorn's case statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528590/dynamic-query-in-ms-sql/528613#528613) is probably the best idea

... but if you really have to use dynamic SQL, you can do it with [sp_executeSQL()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what platform you are using but you can use [Dynamic LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) pretty easily to do this.

```
var query = context.Table
                   .Where( t => t.Id == row_id )
                   .Select( "Col_" + column_id );

IEnumerator enumerator = query.GetEnumerator();
enumerator.MoveNext();
object columnValue = enumerator.Current;
```

Presumably, you'll know which actual type to cast this to depending on the column.  The nice thing about this is you get the parameterized query for free, protecting you against SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't something you should ever need to do if your database is correctly designed. I'd revisit the design of that element of the schema to remove the need to do this.